# Predicting an ordered sequence of future events?

Tags: scala, machine-learning, prediction

Please advise on methods and models for prediction of future events sequenced in time based on some event history. Is Spark MLib or Weka machine learning libraries are good for that?

I need to solve the following problem:

Input data: a huge (750 GB) set of records with user reading history, where record has the following structure:

```
userId, title, author, genre, date_read
```

Task: Given partial reading history of a user predict **what next titles and in what oreder** she will most probably read?
To be more precise: system must predict an ordered sequence of next titles for a user who has read just a few ones from all available titles in the data set. In other words predict ordered sequence of titles for a user who just started reading.

Comment: From their website: `Yes, it is possible to apply Weka to big data!`. But I'd say you best try the libraries out and see if they work for you. If its not fast enough you could try presampling a random subset of the data: Maybe you can discard a portion of the 750 GB without sacrificing a relevant amount of predictive precision.

Comment: Regarding model selection: I assume you can use the data of all users, not just a single user? Then, this looks like a standard **collaborative filtering** problem. I also suggest you try to combine various approaches (i.e., creating a hybrid approach), e.g., using linear regression, as this may have a positive impact on your prediction-accuracy.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my update description of the task. It looks like time series problem as well that would require **Markov Chain** model. I wonder if it is possible to combine **collaborative filtering** and **Markov Chain** approach?

Comment: It's impossible to decide what approach works best for your specific data without trying. Just remember to **cross-validate** your models to avoid overfitting. Regarding Markov Chains: Sounds as if books that are read today are less likely to be read in the future: You could start with a fairly naive approach: Average the `date_read` of each **book** and not recommend books where the average is below a date threshold (e.g., older than a month); Or try to combine an approach that ignores the date with clustering on the date (e.g., K-Means) or a gaussian mixture model.

Comment: How about classics? These are books that people read in all times and that never get out of fashion. I forgot to tell that my data is a set of fiction books. Also in this task it is importatnt to predict not just what books user will read, but also the **in what order** user will read these titles. So in fact the task is to determin how reader tastes evolve over time.

Comment: While it is possible that the `date_read` is distributed uniformly for some books, it is almost certainly the exception. I'd expect the distribution to be gaussian-ish; try it out: Choose some random books and plot their `date_read` over all users; this will give you a hint on what model is best suited. Ultimately, `date_read` is a feature of your data point - just like `genre`, `author` and `title`. A naive approach to determine the order would be to take the group of similar (recommended) books and order them by their overall average `date_read`.

Comment: Will it make sense to replace `date_read` with just a sequence number? In this problem, to my mind, absolute dates do not mean anything, while order in user reading sequence is important. What do you think?

Comment: I would've suggested we move the conversation to a chat, but  you don't have enough reputation to write there. I don't think it's a good idea to replace `date_read` with a sequence number: The semantics of an absolute date would be something like: "In this month, many people read book X, so person Y who likes similar books may be interested in reading X around the same time" (think: Bestseller) while a sequence number would mean: "Many people read book X as their 10th book, so person Y (who read 9 books) may be interested in reading X" (think: becoming educated enough to understand X)